# How would I pass the value of a function parameter to a variable?

Tags: python

How would I go about assigning the value of the 'ip parameter' to a variable so I can print that value?

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

device = ConnectHandler(device_type="cisco_ios", ip="192.168.117.2", 
username="ccna", password="cisco")

connected_device = ip

if device.is_alive():
    print (f"IP Address of connected device is: {connected_device}")

device.disconnect()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "c:/Users/Main/Documents/Visual Studio Code 
>       Projects/Python_Projects/cisco_router_test.py",
>       line 5, in 
>           connected_device = ip
>       NameError: name 'ip' is not defined

Answer (score 2):

You have to define ip outside of ConnectHandler, as it's only passing it as a variable and not assigning it:

```
ip="192.168.117.2"
```

You could ask for input and use it like this:

```
ipaddr = input("Enter IP: ")

device = ConnectHandler(device_type="cisco_ios", ip=ipaddr, 
username="ccna", password="cisco")

connected_device = ipaddr
```

Comment: @BrandonHarmon  see my update, is that what your looking for

Comment: Yea, true, that would work.  I was thinking more in the testing phase, as I usually call the function 
 and pass the parameters directly while testing the program.  But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `:=` in python 3.8:

```
device = ConnectHandler(device_type="cisco_ios", ip := "192.168.117.2", 
username="ccna", password="cisco")

connected_device = ip
```